# How to do intelligent decimal cut off in Java?

Tags: java, formatting, numbers

I want to implement or use some library for an intelligent decimal cut off.

I mean that I would like to get: from 3.456432 -> 3.4, from 0.0000023232432 -> 0.000002 and from 0.000000000001 -> 0.0 (or something like that). I need this feature for a convinient user GUI.

Thereby I need to reduce number of digits that are not equal to zero. I need to keep 1-3 most significant digits and other set to zero.

Comment: If you are rounding then 3.456432 should round to 3.46.

Comment: It seems like you need to figure out what you mean by "intelligent cut-off". Implementation should be easy after that. From your examples it sounds like you want to round to both a certain number of significant digits and a certain absolute precision?

Comment: What do you mean by intelligent decimal cut off?

Comment: I need to reduce number of digits that are not equal to zero. I need to keep 1-3 most significant digits and other set to zero.

Comment: I believe this is a Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/202302/rounding-to-an-arbitrary-number-of-significant-digits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is of any help, you can use the following method to round a double to a specified number of significant digits. There are however no functionality in the standard API to output the result in a reasonable manner:

```
private static double round(double v, int sigDigits) {
    double f = Math.pow(10, Math.ceil(Math.log10(Math.abs(v))) - sigDigits);
    return Math.round(v/f)*f;
}
```

Comment: It works well for big numbers but for small situation is worst. For example, it rounds 0.000012 as 1.2299999999999999E-5. It's not what I want.

Comment: Not it will be 0.000012. Because in this case we have two significant digits: 1 and 2 so we can't round them.

Answer (score 3):

Have you taken a look at the [`DecimalFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) API?

> `DecimalFormat` is a concrete subclass
>   of `NumberFormat` that formats decimal
>   numbers. It has a variety of features
>   designed to make it possible to parse
>   and format numbers in any locale,
>   including support for Western, Arabic,
>   and Indic digits. It also supports
>   different kinds of numbers, including
>   integers (123), fixed-point numbers
>   (123.4), scientific notation (1.23E4),
>   percentages (12%), and currency
>   amounts ($123). All of these can be
>   localized.

Answer (score 1):

Since Java 5, java.util has a [Formatter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/Formatter.html) class which can do what you need.