# Is there a way to truncate scientific notation numbers in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, floating-point, rounding, scientific-notation, rounding-error

As you all know since it is one of the most asked topic on SO, I am having problems with rounding errors (it isn't actually errors, I am well aware).
Instead of explaining my point, I'll give an example of what possible numbers I have and which input I want to be able to obtain:

Let's say

```
var a = 15 * 1e-9;
alert(a)
```

outputs

```
1.5000000000000002e-8
```

I want to be able to obtain `1.5e-8` instead, but I cannot just multiply by 10e8, round and divide by 10e8 because I don't know if it will be e-8 or e-45 or anything else.

So basically I want to be able to obtain the `1.5000002` part, apply `toFixed(3)` and put back the exponent part.

I could convert into a string and parse but it just doesn't seem right...

Any idea ?

---

(I apologize in advance if you feel this is one of many duplicates, but I could not find a similar question, only related ones)

Gael

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [`toPrecision`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/ToPrecision) method:

```
var a = 15 * 1e-9;
a.toPrecision(2); // "1.5e-8"
```

Comment: This, as documented, gives you a (typeof a ==) "string"; great for output.  If you want to get a "number" back you can do `var b = 1 * a.toPrecision(2);` Beware of rounding in the middle of a computation.

Comment: @Stephen, yes, or `var b = +a.toPrecision(2);` or `var b = Number(a.toPrecision(2));`

Comment: Wasn't expecting an easy solution ! I shall look deeper into documentation next time !

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing scientific work and need to round with significant figures in mind: [Rounding to an arbitrary number of significant digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202302/rounding-to-an-arbitrary-number-of-significant-digits/202476#202476)

Answer (score -2):

```
var a = 15 * 1e-9;

console.log(Number.parseFloat(a).toExponential(2));

//the above formula will display the result in the console as: "1.50e-8"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).