# remove latitude and longitude fraction part after 6 digit

Tags: android, latitude-longitude

i get lat and long in this format

Latitude23.132679999999997, Longitude72.20081833333333

but i want to in this format

Latitude = 23.132680 and Longitude 72.200818

how can i convert

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
double Latitude = 23.132679999999997;
int precision =  Math.pow(10, 6);
double new_Latitude = double((int)(precision * Latitude))/precision;
```

This will give you only 6 digits after decimal point.

Comment: The code won't compile since Math.pow(10, 6) returns a double and not an int.

Answer (score 5):

```
double d=23.132679999999997;
DecimalFormat dFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.######"); 

d= Double.valueOf(dFormat .format(d));
```

Answer (score 2):

Once I solved my problem like this -

```
String.format("%.6f", latitude);
```

Return value is string. So you can use this if you need string result.

If you need double you can convert using `Double.parseDouble()` method.

Answer (score 1):

So you want [round a double to an arbitrary number of digits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1581007/914874), don't you?

Answer (score 0):

can use like

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###,##0.00");
System.out.println(df.format(364565.14343));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Latitude and Longitude as String then you can do

```
latitude = latitude.substring(0,latitude.indexOf(".")+6);
```

Of course you should check that there are at least 6 characters after "." by checking string length

Comment: Java variable names are start with lowercase letter & Classe names are start with uppercase letter. Try to maintain the conversion. At first glance I thought Latitude is the class name.