# Lat-long get changed every time i fetch lat-long using fused location api even when i am still at same position

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fusedlocation

i am fetching my current location lat-long using android used location api after every 30 sec but lat-long get changed every time even when i am at the same position.

So please tell me how resolve this issue i wanna get accurate location and same same location if i am at the same position.

Comment: When you get location , google can't give you exact location every time. there is always some minor differences in location.

Comment: what do you mean by changed? if you are using "=" then even .0000001 and .0000002 will not be equal.

Comment: One solution is there : when you get location check difference, if there is minor deference (about 20 -40 meters) then keep last location otherwise update new location.

Comment: its happen only if your are get location form network as well GPS, i also agree with @ChiragSavsani 's comment

Comment: @kay last 3-4 digits get changed everytime,

Comment: Than how does google map mange to show exact location everytime.?

Comment: Round of to third decimal place. It will show exact position on map and will be less sensitive to movement

Comment: what you have tried yet show us code...

Comment: @Kay how should i round of please elaborate..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10599808/remove-latitude-and-longitude-fraction-part-after-6-digit

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the fact that the received position change (even if very little) as a function of all the factors that influence the sending of GPS signals. You can obviate this drawback by introducing a tolerance factor of the measurement such as whether the coordinates fall within a area of 30 m the position is the same.

Make sure that your program takes into account not only the position of the four or five final numbers that change constantly.