# parseFloat.toPreceision just adds zeros

Tags: javascript, numbers, parsefloat

I'm sending the number/string 0.001 to a the function below:

```
SignificantFigures = 4;
function LimitNumberOfDigits(num) {
    var tempStr = "";
    if (isNaN(num))
        return "\xD8";
    else{
        if (parseFloat(num) === 0 || (num.toString().indexOf('.') === -1 && parseInt(num) < 9999) || num.toString().length <= 4) {
            return num;
        }
        tempStr = parseFloat(num).toPrecision(SignificantFigures);
        if (tempStr.indexOf("e") > -1) {
            var startE = tempStr.indexOf("e");
            var endE = 0;
            for (var i = startE +2 ; i < tempStr.length; i++ ) { // + to ignore e and sign (+ or - )
                if(parseInt(tempStr[i], 10) > 0) {
                    endE = i;
                }else {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (startE + 2 === endE) {
                var pow = tempStr[endE];
            } else {
                var pow = tempStr.substring(startE +2 ,endE);
            }
            return tempStr.substring(0,startE) + "*10<sup>"+ pow +"</sup>";
        }else {
            return parseFloat(num).toPrecision(SignificantFigures);
        }
    }
}
```

When im sending 0.2 or even 0.11 im getting like 0.2000 and 0.1100.
The issue here is the toPrecision acts like ToFixed.
Ideas?

**EDIT**

What i want? simple as that, if a numbers needs to be changed e.g 0.012312312041 it should be 0.0123 , numbers like 0.12 or 28 should stay the same.

Comment: The behavior of `toPrecision` and `toFixed` will be the same for those numbers. E.g. 0.2 to 2 significant figures = 0.20. That's because leading zeros *are not significant*. Try it with 0.004 to 3 sig figs vs 0.004 `toFixed(3)` - you'll see a difference then.

Comment: so what do i have to do in order to keep numbers that i dont need to convert?

Comment: also numbers like 28 turns into 28.00

Comment: k, so what can i add to this function to do what i need?

Comment: Simple. Convert the number to a string first. Then check the length of the string. If it's too long, then set the precision of the number. Voila! Short numbers stay short, long numbers get shortened.

Comment: This answer may be what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/a/202476/1402923

Comment: @enhzflep look the function now, is it better?
added condition to 2nd if statment about length

Comment: @VeraGavriel - I didn't try the function before it's modification. I think you forgot to test it before posting this? I've just tried your code with the following numbers, 10.00005, 10.00006, 0.012312312041, 0.12 and 28. Unfortunately, the results are: 10.00, 10.00, 0.01231, 0.12 and 28. So, the code works in places and fails in others. :( For the two values of 10.00, you need to account for the number of digits found before the decimal place. I.e toPrecision(4) won't work. You'll need toPrecision(6) for those two.

Comment: @enhzflep i need them to be 10 and not 10.0000 thats the problem..now they are 10.00 .. irrelevent zeros after period

Comment: @VeraGavriel - If I could make a suggestion, please update the question with your refined requirements. You said that `0.012312312041` should display as `0.0123` - by extension, (using the same rules) `10.00005` and `10.00006` should have 4 digits after the decimal point. If you don't want to display 10.0000, then after you've reduced it to having 4 places following the decimal point, add a test to see if all digits following the decimal place are 0. If they are, then simply discard the decimal point and all digits that follow it. I suggest you add some (more) numbers and the expected result.

Comment: @enhzflep already added it in my first edit. look what i want to have.

Comment: @VeraGavriel - Yeah, I saw that already - you can see from my second comment that I already used those 3 pairs of input/expected output. I merely used 10.00005 and 10.00006 to check for rounding behaviour. You'll need to provide a more comprehensive set of inputs and their expected outputs to get better answers!