# How can I round to an arbitrary number of significant digits with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, rounding, significant-digits

I tried below sample code

```
function sigFigs(n, sig) {
    if ( n === 0 )
        return 0
    var mult = Math.pow(10,
        sig - Math.floor(Math.log(n < 0 ? -n: n) / Math.LN10) - 1);
    return Math.round(n * mult) / mult;
 }
```

But this function is not working for inputs like 
sigFigs(24730790,3) returns 24699999.999999996
and sigFigs(4.7152e-26,3) returns: 4.7200000000000004e-26

If anybody has working example please share.
Thanks.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can try javascript inbuilt method-

```
Number( my_number.toPrecision(3) )
```

For Your case try

```
Number( 24730790.0.toPrecision(5) )
```

For your refrence and working example you can see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202302/rounding-to-an-arbitrary-number-of-significant-digits)

Comment: Works but not for integers (in Chrome). Use `parseFloat(number.toPrecision(precision))`. Thanks @Gianluca Casati

Answer (score 7):

First of all thanks to everybody, it would be a hard task without these snippets shared.

My value added, is the following snippet (see below for complete implementation)

```
parseFloat(number.toPrecision(precision))
```

Please note that if number is, for instance, 10000 and precision is 2, then `number.toPrecision(precision)` will be '1.0e+4' but `parseFloat` understands exponential notation.

It is also worth to say that, believe it or not, the algorithm using `Math.pow` and logarithms posted above, when run on test case `formatNumber(5, 123456789)` was giving a success on Mac (node v12) but rising and error on Windows (node v10). It was weird so we arrived at the solution above.

At the end I found this as the definitive implementation, taking advantage of all feedbacks provided in this post. Assuming we have a *formatNumber.js* file with the following content

```
/**
 * Format number to significant digits.
 *
 * @param {Number} precision
 * @param {Number} number
 *
 * @return {String} formattedValue
 */

export default function formatNumber (precision, number) {
  if (typeof number === 'undefined' || number === null) return ''

  if (number === 0) return '0'

  const roundedValue = round(precision, number)
  const floorValue = Math.floor(roundedValue)

  const isInteger = Math.abs(floorValue - roundedValue) < Number.EPSILON

  const numberOfFloorDigits = String(floorValue).length
  const numberOfDigits = String(roundedValue).length

  if (numberOfFloorDigits > precision) {
    return String(floorValue)
  } else {
    const padding = isInteger ? precision - numberOfFloorDigits : precision - numberOfDigits + 1

    if (padding > 0) {
      if (isInteger) {
        return `${String(floorValue)}.${'0'.repeat(padding)}`
      } else {
        return `${String(roundedValue)}${'0'.repeat(padding)}`
      }
    } else {
      return String(roundedValue)
    }
  }
}

function round (precision, number) {
  return parseFloat(number.toPrecision(precision))
}
```

If you use *tape* for tests, here there are some basic tests

```
import test from 'tape'

import formatNumber from '..path/to/formatNumber.js'

test('formatNumber', (t) => {
  t.equal(formatNumber(4, undefined), '', 'undefined number returns an empty string')
  t.equal(formatNumber(4, null), '', 'null number return an empty string')

  t.equal(formatNumber(4, 0), '0')
  t.equal(formatNumber(4, 1.23456789), '1.235')
  t.equal(formatNumber(4, 1.23), '1.230')
  t.equal(formatNumber(4, 123456789), '123500000')
  t.equal(formatNumber(4, 1234567.890123), '1235000')
  t.equal(formatNumber(4, 123.4567890123), '123.5')
  t.equal(formatNumber(4, 12), '12.00')
  t.equal(formatNumber(4, 1.2), '1.200')
  t.equal(formatNumber(4, 1.234567890123), '1.235')
  t.equal(formatNumber(4, 0.001234567890), '0.001235')

  t.equal(formatNumber(5, 123456789), '123460000')

  t.end()
})
```

Answer (score 5):

How about automatic type casting, which takes care of exponential notation?

```
f = (x, n) => +x.toPrecision(n)
```

Testing:

```
> f (0.123456789, 6)
0.123457
> f (123456789, 6)
123457000
> f (-123456789, 6)
-123457000
> f (-0.123456789, 6)
-0.123457
> f (-0.123456789, 2)
-0.12
> f (123456789, 2)
120000000
```

And it returns a number and not a string.

Comment: Thanks, that was very nice. Saves me quite a bit of work.

Answer (score 5):

## Using pure math (i.e. no strings involved)

You can round a value to any arbitrary number of significant figures simply by first calculating the largest power of ten that the number contains, and then use that to calculate the precision to which the number should be rounded.

```js
/**
 * Rounds a value to a given number of significant figures
 * @param value The number to round
 * @param significanFigures The number of significant figures
 * @returns The value rounded to the given number of significant figures
 */
const round = (value, significantFigures) => {
  const exponent = Math.floor(Math.log10(value))
  const nIntegers = exponent + 1
  const precision = 10 ** (nIntegers - significantFigures)
  return Math.round(value / precision) * precision
}
```

> In the above code, `precision` simply means the closest multiple we want to round to. For example, if we want to round to the closest multiple of 100, the precision is 100. If we want to round to the closest multiple of 0.1, i.e. to one decimal place, the precision is 0.1.
>
> The `exponent` is simply the exponent of the largest power of 10 contained in value. Continue reading below, if you're interested in knowing where this comes from.
>
> `nIntegers` is the number of integers (digits to the left of the decimal place) in the value.

Some examples

```js
> round(173.25, 1)
200
> round(173.25, 2)
170
> round(173.25, 3)
173
> round(173.25, 4)
173.3
> round(173.25, 5)
173.25
```

## An intuitive and educative explanation

Generally, we can round any number to a given precision, by first "moving the decimal place" in one direction (division), then rounding the number to the nearest integer, and finally moving the decimal place back to its original position (multiplication).

```js
const rounded = Math.round(value / precision) * precision
```

For example, to round a value to the closest multiple of *10*, the precision is set to *10*  and we get

```js
> Math.round(173.25 / 10) * 10
170
```

Similarly, if we want to round a value to one decimal place, i.e. find the closest multiple of *0.1*, the precision is set to *0.1*

```js
> Math.round(173.25 / 0.1) * 0.1
173.3
```

> Here the `precision` simply means "the closest multiple we want to round to".

So how do we use this knowledge to round a value to any given number of significant figures then?

The problem we have to solve is to determine the precision we should round to, given the number of significant figures. Say we want to round the value *12345.67* to three significant figures. How do we determine that the precision should be *100*, in this case?

> The precision should be *100* because `Math.round(12345.67 / 100) * 100` gives *12300*, i.e. rounded to three significant figures.

It's actually really easy to solve.

Basically, what we have to do is to 1) determine how many digits there are on the left side of the decimal place and then 2) use that to determine how many steps to "move the decimal place" before rounding the number.

We start by counting the number of digits in the integer part of the number (that is, *5* digits) and subtract the number of significant figures we want to round to (*3* digits). The result, *5 - 3 = 2*, is the number of steps we should move the decimal place to the left (if the result was negative we would move the decimal place to the right).

In order to move the decimal place two steps to the left, we have to use the precision *10^2 = 100*. In other words, the result gives us the power to which *10* should be raised in order to get the precision.

```
n_integer = "number of digits in the integer part of the number" = 5
n_significant = "the number of significant figures we want to round" = 3
precision = 10 ** (n_integer - n_significant)
```

That's it!

But, hey, wait a minute! You haven't actually showed us how to code this! Also, you said we didn't want to use strings. How do we count the number of digits in the integer part of the number without converting it to a string? Well, we don't have to use strings for that. Math comes to the rescue!

We know that a real value *v* can be expressed as a power of ten (using ten because we're working in the decimal system). That is, *v = 10^a*. If we now only take the integer part of *a*, let's call that *a'*, the new value *v' = 10^a'* will be the largest power of *10* contained in *v*. The number of digits in *v* is the same as in *v'*, which is *a' + 1*. As such, we have shown that ***n_integer = a' + 1***, where ***a' = floor(log10(v))***.

In code this looks like

```js
const exponent = Math.floor(Math.log10(v)) // a'
const nIntegers = exponent + 1
```

And, as we had from before, the precision is

```js
const precision = 10 ** (nInteger - nSignificant)
```

And, finally, the rounding

```js
return Math.round(value / precision) * precision
```

> **Example**
> Say we want to round the value *v = 12345.67* to *1* significant figure. For the above code to work, the precision has to be *precision = 10000 = 10^(n_integers - 1)*.
>
> If we wanted to round to *6* significant figures, the precision would have to be *precision = 0.1 = 10^(n_integers - 6)*.
>
> Generally, the precision has to be *precision = 10^(n_integers - n_significant)*

## A fun side effect

Using this code and knowledge, you can round a number to the closest multiple of any value, not just the plain old and boring powers of *10* (i.e. *{..., 1000, 100, 10, 1, 0.1, 0.01, ...}*). No, with this you can, for example, round to the closest multiple of, say, *0.3*.

```js
> Math.round(4 / 0.3) * 0.3
3.9
```

> *0.3 * 13 = 3.9*, which is the multiple of *0.3* closest to *4*.

Comment: There are cases in which the proposed code will give somewhat unsatisfactory results when the resulting number is converted back to string; for example `round(100, 8)` will output `100.00000000000001`. I've observed that better results can be obtained by multiplying first instead of dividing first, i.e. change `10 ** (…)` to `10 ** -(…)` and then `Math.round(value * precision) / precision`. (I'll admit I don't quite understand why that is - these subtle floating point math shenanigans tend to go way over my head.)

Comment: Another small problem with the proposed code is that it will return NaN on negative numbers. This can be fixed by simply changing `Math.log10(value)` to `Math.log10(Math.abs(value))`.

Comment: > round(1, 5) = 0.9999999999999999

Got to love javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the inbuilt method will give you silly results when the number is > 10, like exponent notation etc.

I made a function, which should solve the issue (maybe not the most elegant way of writing it but here it goes):

```
function(value, precision) {
  if (value < 10) {
    value = parseFloat(value).toPrecision(precision)
  } else {
    value = parseInt(value)
    let significantValue = value
    for (let i = value.toString().length; i > precision; i--) {
      significantValue = Math.round(significantValue / 10)
    }
    for (let i = 0; significantValue.toString().length < value.toString().length; i++ ) {
      significantValue = significantValue * 10
    }
    value = significantValue
  }
  return value
}
```

If you prefer having exponent notation for the higher numbers, feel free to use toPrecision() method.

Comment: I tried using your function on `(123456, 3)`, and it gave me `124000` instead of `123000`. Probably the rounding of units carries over until the hundreds.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to specify significant figures left of the decimal place and replace extraneous placeholders with T B M K respectively

```js
// example to 3 sigDigs (significant digits)
//54321 = 54.3M
//12300000 = 12.3M

const moneyFormat = (num, sigDigs) => {
   var s = num.toString();
   let nn = "";
   for (let i = 0; i <= s.length; i++) {
      if (s[i] !== undefined) {
         if (i < sigDigs) nn += s[i];
         else nn += "0";
      }
   }
   nn = nn
      .toString()
      .replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")
      .replace(",000,000,000", "B")
      .replace(",000,000", "M")
      .replace(",000", "k");
   if (
      nn[nn.length - 4] === "," &&
      nn[nn.length - 2] === "0" &&
      nn[nn.length - 1] === "0"
   ) {
      let numLetter = "K";
      if (parseInt(num) > 999999999999) numLetter = "T";
      else if (parseInt(num) > 999999999) numLetter = "B";
      else if (parseInt(num) > 999999) numLetter = "M";
      console.log("numLetter: " + numLetter);
      nn = nn.toString();
      let nn2 = ""; // new number 2
      for (let i = 0; i < nn.length - 4; i++) {
         nn2 += nn[i];
      }
      nn2 += "." + nn[nn.length - 3] + numLetter;
      nn = nn2;
   }

   return nn;
};
```