# double granularity affecting numeric comparisons c++

Tags: c++, bit, double-precision, granularity

Below is a test block of code that is supposed to determine equivalency of 2 doubles within a tolerance.

```
double lhs_1 = 0.02;
double lhs_2 = 0.04;
double rhs = 0.03;
double tolerance = 0.01;

bool is_match_1 = (abs(lhs_1 - rhs) <= tolerance);
bool is_match_2 = (abs(lhs_2 - rhs) <= tolerance);
```

However is_match_2 turns out false where is_match_1 turns out true. I understand that numbers stored in the computer are discreet values and not continuous. Can someone share a solution? I would like to err on the side of passing the test within reason. Is there a way to increment the value of a double by 1 for whatever precision it currently has (I am not familiar with the bit layout of a double)? Because I might just increment the tolerance value to allow for this granularity issue.

**EDIT:**

When this is really implemented the user will define inputs and tolerances, so I'm just trying to give them an expected output for whatever values they enter.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison

Comment: which unit-testing library are you using?  Most packages, like googletest, have a EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ() to their standard EXPECT_EQ(), which will handle this for you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245870/next-higher-lower-ieee-double-precision-number explains how to find the next biggest double.  Though this probably wouldn't be useful for the tolerance; if you do a few calculations your error is likely to be bigger than this.

Comment: That is pretty tight tolerance, isn't it? What if the difference is 0.0100000000000000001?

Comment: Those numbers look like they are money values. You should probably represent them using integers as pounds and pence, or micro-pence according to requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are no "good" rules for choosing the tolerance.

You have at your disposal the "machine epsilon"

```
double epsilon = std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()
```

which is the smallest value which, added to one, gives a result different from one.

I usually write my tolerances as a function of epsilon. There are no good rules, but for instance comparing like this

```
bool fuzzy_equals(double a, double b)
{
    static const double eps = std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon();
    return std::fabs(b - a) < 1024 * eps * std::max(a, b);
}
```

works well in many cases. You can adjust the 1024, I like powers of two, but you might not. The actual value you choose is problem-dependent. Epsilon for doubles is around 10^-16, so 1024 is quite small, and you will need a bigger number in many cases *(virtually any operation, including the minus operation inside `fuzzy_equals` will "eat" one epsilon -- they can cancel out, but on average, `n` operations mean `sqrt(n) * epsilon` precision, so 1024 corresponds to the expected precision after one million operations)*.

In other cases, where the precision is not as good, for instance when testing the minimum of a function against a known value (minima are usually only determined up to sqrt(eps) accuracy), I use

```
bool fuzzy_equals2(double a, double b)
{
    static const double eps = std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon();
    return std::fabs(b - a) < 1024 * std::sqrt(eps) * std::max(a, b);
}
```

I often use other functions, like `std::pow(eps, something)`, or even `-1 / std::log(eps)`. This depends on what prior information I can derive from the problem, and what is the error I **expect**.

When it comes to code structure, I use a functional approach and pass a *comparer* to my algorithms, a bit like STL predicates. This enables you not to hardcode the logic of comparing into your algorithms.

In short, there is no one-size-fits-all rule. You have to choose depending on the problem

Answer (score 2):

[Comparing floating point numbers](http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm) might be of some help here or perhaps [Why doesn't my floating point comparison work?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/newbie.html#faq-29.17)

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of having a tolerance is avoiding straightforward equality checks. They don't really work for doubles, as you've just learned the hard way. In the world of doubles, 1+1 may not equal 2 (as internally it might be something like 1.99999743).

So "Difference *equals* tolerance" is not a reliable condition. Tolerance should be 1-2 orders of magnitude smaller than the sensible difference between values, as opposed as *same as expected difference*. So if you wanna check if lhs_2 - rhs is equal to rhs - lhs_1 within tolerance, the following check would serve you better:

```
fabs((lhs_2 - rhs) - (rhs - lhs_1)) < 0.0001
```

Comment: 1+1 will likely always exactly equal 2. But 0.1 will often not be exact.

Comment: Instructing by crude example here :) It's a perfectly good technique for drawing one's attention :)

Answer (score 0):

Your tolerance is already very loose - 0.01 is HUGE compared to the numbers you're comparing. Just open it up to 0.01000001 and you'll be fine.