# Comparison vs. Double.MaxValue

Tags: c#, double, floating-accuracy

When comparing vary large doubles it happens that the following test fails:

```
[Test]
public void DoubleMaxValueTest()
{
    double val = Double.MaxValue;
    double epsilon = 10000.0;
    Assert.IsTrue(val > (Double.MaxValue - epsilon));
}
```

Being aware that doubles are represented as mantissa, exponent and a sign bit it is due to the fact that the value Double.MaxValue - 10000 is actually represented the same way as Double.MaxValue (these values are equal).

The question is: How to get the smallest epsilon for which this test returns true?

Comment: If you understand why the test fails, it would be best if you made that clear *from the start of your question* rather than changing the question at the last part.

Comment: Look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330644/get-next-smallest-double-number).

Comment: @Jon: You are right, I hope that now it is more clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer the *final* question, as it sounds like you actually understand why the test fails...

IEEE-754 has a neat property that if you take adjacent bitwise values, those end up being adjacent representable `double` values. So you can find the "second highest" representable `double` by treating the bit pattern for `MaxValue` as an integer, subtracting 1, and turning the result back into a `double`:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        long maxDoubleBits = BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(Double.MaxValue);
        double nextLargestDouble = BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble(maxDoubleBits - 1);
        double difference = double.MaxValue - nextLargestDouble;
        Console.WriteLine(difference);
    }
}
```

The result is 1.99584030953472E+292

Now, that difference is the *actual* difference between `MaxValue` and the next highest value. So the smallest amount that you can subtract from `double.MaxValue` to get a value which *isn't* `MaxValue` is actually `difference / 2`.