# Probability of generating a particular random number, such as in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, random, probability

In real probability, there is a 0% chance that a random number `p`, selected from all of the real numbers in the interval `(0,1)`, will be `0.5`.  However, what are the odds that

```
rand == 0.5
```

in MATLAB?  I suppose this is like asking how many double-precision numbers are between zero and one, or maybe there are other factors at play.

Comment: See: [How many double numbers are there between 0.0 and 1.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978930/). However, if I recall correctly, the Mersenne Twister algorithm calculates based on [1,2) and then shifts.

Comment: I may be wrong about this (can't quite remember from a long time ago), but I believe that the probability that `p` will equal 0.5 is actually undefined, not 0. When defining distributions over uncountable sets such as a real interval, the only probabilities that are defined are for when `p` is a member of some subset `s` of the interval, where `s` must have a (Lebesgue?) measure greater than zero. Sorry that doesn't directly answer your main question about doubles, but maybe it helps to think in that context.

Comment: @SamRoberts: The proper terminology from [sigma algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-algebra) for this is "[almost surely](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely)," commonly abbreviated a.s.

Comment: @SamRoberts: well, [at least a few people say that it's actually well-defined, and that the probability is indeed zero](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155156/)...

Comment: @horchler Now it's starting to come back - thank you, I shall enjoy reminding myself about what sigma algebras are!

Comment: It's further complicated because most PRNG's are actually based on integers (for precision reasons), and then scaled to rationals.  If the divisor is odd then 1/2 is mathematically impossible. But then in converting to a floating point there's usually some approximating in getting to the nearest possible float/double representation, so 0.5 may become possible again because of the inexact mapping.  Without knowing the exact specification for MATLAB's generator and the specifics of the rational -> floating point conversion, you can't say for sure whether or not 0.5 is a possible outcome.

Answer (score 1):

No particular info on MATLAB's generator...

In general even simple [pseudo-random generators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) have long enough cycles which would cover all values representable by double.

If MATLAB uses some other form of generating random numbers it would be even better - so assuming it uniformly covers whole range of double values.

I believe probability would be: distance between representable numbers around values you are interested divided by length of the interval. See [What is the minimal step in double data type? (.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478774/what-is-the-minimal-step-in-double-data-type-net) for discussion on the distance.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978930/how-many-double-numbers-are-there-between-0-0-and-1-0), we see that there are 2<sup>62</sup> - 2<sup>52</sup>
doubles in the interval (0 1). Therefore, the probability of picking any single one (like 0.5) would be roughly equal to one divided by this number, or

```
>> p = 1/(2^62-2^52) 
ans =
    2.170523997312134e-019
```

However, as horchler already indicates, it also depends on the type of random number generator you use, as well as MATLAB's implementation thereof. Sadly, I have only basic knowledge on the implementaion details for each, but you can look [here](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/randstream.list.html) for a list of available random number generators in MATLAB and google a bit further for more precise numbers.

Comment: Note that most of the points between 0 and 1 will be closer to 0 than to 1, thus I guess your estimate is more of a lower bound.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: That is true...Does the Mersienne Twister pick any `double` from (0,1) with equal probability, or any `number`? If the first is the case, my answer is correct. But I indeed expect the *second* case to be the algorithm's aim, therefore, you'd have to look at the two separate intervals `(0,X)` and `(X, 1)` (with `X = 0.5` in this case) and rework the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether Alexei was trying to say this, but inspired by him I think the probability will indeed be approximately the distance between numbers around 0.5.

Therefore I expect the probability to be approximately:

```
eps(0.5)
```

Which evaluates to  1.1102e-16

---

Given the monotonic nature of the difference between double numbers I would actually think this holds:

```
eps(0.5-eps(0.5)) <= yourprobability  <= eps(0.5)
```

Implying a range of 5.5511e-17 to 1.1102e-16