# Printing Significant Digits

Tags: c#, .net, number-formatting

I'm attempting to create graph axis labels -- the physical text.  I know how to get the labels and print them using GDI, but my algorithm doesn't do a great job of printing with fractional steps.

To print the labels, I currently get the first label and then add a step to each label that follows:

```
public static void PrintLabels(double start, double end, double step);
{
    double current = start;

    while (current <= end)
    {
        gfx.DrawString(current.ToString(),...); 
        current += step;
    }
}
```

Is there a `number.ToString("something")` that will print out decimals if they are there, otherwise just the whole part?  I would first check if either start, end, or step contains a fractional part, then if yes, print all labels with a decimal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the custom format strings here :http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx
I think I understand your question... does

```
   current.ToString("#0.#");
```

give you the behavior you are asking for?  I often use `"#,##0.####"` for similar labels.
Also, see this question: [Formatting numbers with significant figures in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158172/formatting-numbers-with-significant-figures-in-c)

Comment: It's odd .ToString("0.##") isn't the default format for converting decimal to string in C#, but that does get you what you'd most likely want - up to 2 decimal places, only if they're non-zero.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with using a custom format string, but the [standard general numeric format string ("G")](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#GFormatString) will work fine in this case too as I was recently reminded:

```
current.ToString("G");
```

Here is a quick, self-contained example that juxtaposes the custom and standard format-string approaches...

```
double foo = 3.0;
double bar = 3.5;

// first with custom format strings
Console.WriteLine(foo.ToString("#0.#"));
Console.WriteLine(bar.ToString("#0.#"));

// now with standard format strings
Console.WriteLine(foo.ToString("G"));
Console.WriteLine(bar.ToString("G"));
```

..., which yields:

```
3
3.5
3
3.5
```