# How to round System.Decimal in .Net to a number of significant figures

Tags: c#, math, decimal, rounding

I have a System.Decimal number

0.00123456789

and I wish to round to 3 significant figures. I expect

0.00123

with the behaviour to be a rounding behaviour rather than truncation. Is there a bullet proof way to do this in .Net?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158172/formatting-numbers-with-significant-figures-in-c-sharp.  This question has a great explanation which may help.

Comment: Those answers all deal with double. I was curious if there is a specific technique for base 10 (decimal) numbers which should be easier to deal with.

Comment: But the answer given there does work.

Comment: You will first have to write a version of Math.Log10() that works for Decimal.  That's extremely painful.  Converting it to a string and then counting off digits is ugly but not painful.

Comment: @HansPassant Considering that then on top of the Math.Log10 a Math.Ceiling is done, and that double have a bigger range (but smaller precision), could there be an error using the Math.Log10(double)? And if yes, where should it be searched?

Comment: The double version isn't accurate enough for decimal.  If you don't mind sometimes getting one too many or few digits when the value is close to a power of 10 then it is okay.  People tend to mind, it is an ugly entry in the bug database that will nag you for a very long time.

Answer (score 5):

You can try this... But I don't guarantee anything... Written and tested in 20 minutes and based on Pyrolistical's code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1581007/613130
There is a big difference in that he uses a `long` for the `shifted` variable (because a `double` has a precision of 15-16 digits, while a `long` has 18-19, so a `long` is enough), while I use a `decimal` (because `decimal` has a precision of 28-29 digits).

```
public static decimal RoundToSignificantFigures(decimal num, int n)
{
    if (num == 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    // We are only looking for the next power of 10... 
    // The double conversion could impact in some corner cases,
    // but I'm not able to construct them...
    int d = (int)Math.Ceiling(Math.Log10((double)Math.Abs(num)));
    int power = n - d;

    // Same here, Math.Pow(10, *) is an integer number
    decimal magnitude = (decimal)Math.Pow(10, power);

    // I'm using the MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero . I'm not sure
    // having a MidpointRounding.ToEven would be useful (is Banker's
    // rounding used for significant figures?)
    decimal shifted = Math.Round(num * magnitude, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
    decimal ret = shifted / magnitude;

    return ret;
}
```

If you don't trust the `(int)Math.Ceiling(Math.Log10((double)` you could use this:

```
private static readonly decimal[] Pows = Enumerable.Range(-28, 57)
    .Select(p => (decimal)Math.Pow(10, p))
    .ToArray();

public static int Log10Ceiling(decimal num)
{
    int log10 = Array.BinarySearch(Pows, num);
    return (log10 >= 0 ? log10 : ~log10) - 28;
}
```

I have written it in another 20 minutes (and yes, I have tested all the `Math.Pow((double), p)` for all the values -28 - +28). It seems to work, and it's only 20% slower than the C# formula based on `double`s). It's based on a static array of pows and a `BinarySearch`. Luckily the `BinarySearch` already "suggests" the next element when it can't find one :-), so the `Ceiling` is for free.

Comment: Are you expecting your return variable to always be positive? Why `num >= 0 ? ret : -ret`

Comment: @DerrickMoeller If the BinarySearch doesn't find the searched item exactly, it returns a negative number that is the negation (~) of the index of the first element greater than the searched value.

Comment: I'm not referring to the BinarySearch, you do it again in `RoundToSignificantFigures`?

Comment: @DerrickMoeller Probably a wrong copy-paste from an older version of code :-) Fixed.

Comment: It seems like `Log10Ceiling(1000.000m) should return `4`, but your code is returning `3`.

Comment: @Enigmativity `log10(1000) = 3`. log10(1) = 0, log10(10) = 1, log10(100) = 2 and so on.

Comment: @xanatos - Ah, yeah, maths. :-/

Answer (score 0):

in example:

```
decimal a = 1.9999M;
decimal b = Math.Round(a, 2); //returns 2
```

Answer (score 0):

SqlDecimal has fast methods to calculate and adjust precision.

```
public static decimal RoundToSignificantFigures(decimal num, int n)
{
    SqlDecimal value = New SqlDecimal(num);
    if (value.Precision > num){
        int digits = num - (value.Precision - value.Scale);
        value = SqlDecimal.Round(value, digits);
        value = SqlDecimal.AdjustScale(value, (digits>0 ? digits : 0) - dstValue.Scale, True);
    }
    return value.Value;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this ...   `decimalVar.ToString ("#.##");`