# Compare two doubles with different number of decimal places in C#

Tags: c#, precision, double-precision

I want to compare two doubles `a` and `b` in C# (where for example `b` has more decimal places) in the way that: if I round the number `b` to number of decimal places of `a` i should get the same number if they are the same. Example:

```
double a = 0.123;
double b = 0.1234567890;
```

should be same.

```
double a = 0.123457
double b = 0.123456789
```

should be same.

I cannot write

```
if(Math.Abs(a-b) < eps)
```

because I don't know how to calculate precision `eps`.

Comment: Are you deciding the number of decimal places?

Comment: You may have set up your example wrong.. `a` is already "rounded" to the same number of decimal places as `b`, because `b` has MORE precision... so I'm not quite sure what you're asking.

Comment: A double does not include a concept of significant digits. It uses all the precision it has.  consider e.g. `double a = 1.030;`

Comment: This seems more like a question about significant digits. This page might help: [Formatting numbers with significant figures in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/158172/formatting-numbers-with-significant-figures-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood what you want you could just shift the digits before the decimal place til the "smaller" (i.e. one with least significant figures) is a integer, then compare:
i.e. in some class...

```
static bool comp(double a, double b)
{
    while((a-(int)a)>0 && (b - (int)b)>0)
    {
        a *= 10;
        b *= 10;
    }
    a = (int)a;
    b = (int)b;
    return a == b;
}
```

**Edit**

Clearly calling `(int)x` on a double is asking for trouble since double can store bigger numbers than ints. This is better:

```
while((a-Math.Floor(a))>0 && (b - Math.Floor(b))>0)
//...
```

Comment: I think that this function is not good. For example, I have `b=1.63329` and when it is multiply 2 times with 10 I get `b=163.32899999999998`, so the while loop does not finish and numbers ends up in infinity.

Comment: Fair point - the links in @JasonZ comments is the same in spirit - but using Math.Log finds what you would need to multiply by without getting in a mess with overflows etc

Comment: I bound maximum number of multiplication for example to 15, so the program can exit while loop. I tested it on several number and results looks fine. I will use this solution hopping that it will not produce some mess in future, since I needed this comparison for Unit testing.

Comment: The Math.Log approach may be quicker. Good luck. Or look at the relative sizes. Something like `if (Math.Abs(x-y) < Math.Abs(x)*precision )` ... see http://accu.org/index.php/articles/1558

Answer (score 0):

`double` has epsilon `double.Epsilon` or set prefer error by hardcode, f.e. `0.00001`