# C# three part format display original value

Tags: c#

I am trying to display the original value in C# three part display format. I got unexpected result `+ 29291221321`. I am expecting `+ 29.12121321`. Is this a bug or what am I doing wrong?

```
double value1 = 29.1221321;
string formattingString = $"+ {value1}; - {value1}; 0";
 // returns "+29.1221321; -29.1221321; 0"
Console.WriteLine(value1.ToString(formattingString));
// returns "+ 29291221321"
```

Please refer to why i call ToString at the end. It is something known as three part format to separate outcome quickly based on +, - and 0 value
https://diptimayapatra.wordpress.com/2014/01/13/3-part-format-of-numbers-in-c/

**Note:** 
I am **not expecting** to hardcode by **specify x numbers of #** after decimal places. Please advise if there is a better method of displaying the original decimal value in three part format

```
 string formattingString = "+ #.############; - #.############; 0";
```

Comment: You are putting the value itself into the formatting string, instead of placeholders. It's unclear what kind of formatting string you even want.

Comment: that is quite strange that the semicolon is doing that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated

Comment: `formattingString` isn't a format string, it's the *output* of the string interpolation operations performed by `$"+ {value1}; - {value1}; 0";`.  The second format string works just fine

Comment: Presumably you want to output formattingString directly 
`Console.WriteLine(formattingString);`

Comment: @GSerg i see 2 upvote on your answer but i don't get what you means. Yes i put the value into the formatting string but by the time string formattingString outcome is `+ 29.1221321; - 29.1221321; 0` which is correct at this time. But then when it move to value1.ToString(formattingString) returns `+29291221321`. Why is this so ?

Comment: If you have the value `29.1221321` (code), how should that ever become `+ 29.12121321` in the output? These are different numbers. .122 -> .121

Comment: why do you even use the `.ToString(format)` ? I can't see the goal here.

Comment: @eulercode Your question does not make sense. You have achieved the result that you believe is correct (`+ 29.1221321; - 29.1221321; 0`), why are you trying to further pass that result to `ToString()` if it's already correct? It is not a [formatting string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings) in the first place.

Comment: @GSerg this is C# three part format that i learn to pass +, - and 0 value https://diptimayapatra.wordpress.com/2014/01/13/3-part-format-of-numbers-in-c/

Comment: @Franck this is C# three part format that i learn from a tutorial. The intend is to quickly separate postive, negative and zero. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66549066/c-sharp-three-part-format-display-original-value

Comment: @eulercode You are not doing what you think you are doing. You are supposed to provide a formatting string. You are instead providing a formatted string. It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. You have not explained why `"+ #.############; - #.############; 0"` does not work for you (because that *is* a formatting string).

Comment: @GSerg "+ #.############; - #.############; 0" works for me but i do not want it do it that way ....

Comment: But `$"+ {value1}; - {value1}; 0";` is not a formatting string. See the examples here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tostring?view=net-5.0#System_Double_ToString_System_String_

Comment: Updated my answer with the understanding that you're wanting something like `#.N` where `N` means unlimited decimal places. I don't think what you're asking is possible with the way interpolation works currently.

Comment: @eulercode *Why* don't you want to do it in that way? What is the property of that formatting string that does not work for you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Formatting numbers with significant figures in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158172/formatting-numbers-with-significant-figures-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @HansKeﬆing That is not true for three part formatting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Please advise if there is a better method of displaying the original decimal value in three part format

`#` is already the best way to express what you want, since it will [omit non-significant zeros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings) at the end. A `double` has about [15 to 17 significant digits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types), so you can put 17 `#` at the end of your format specifier to get the original value.

```
double value1 = 1.23456;
string formattingString = "+ #.#################; - #.#################; 0";
Console.WriteLine(value1.ToString(formattingString));
Console.WriteLine((-value1).ToString(formattingString));
Console.WriteLine(0.ToString(formattingString));
```

Output (note the leading spaces, because you have spaces in your format specifier):

```
+ 1,23456
 - 1,23456
 0
```

Check that for a double value with more digits

```
double value1 = 1.2345678901234567890123;   // too many digits for a double
```

and compare it to the output of

```
Console.WriteLine(value1);
```

Comment: Hi, I accept your answer on this. But i have create a new post that requires further explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66549716/c-sharp-three-part-format-output-issue. Hope u can comment there as well why putting `.` inside will cause unpredictable output

Answer (score 0):

You're putting the value into the format specifier instead of your specifier:

```
string formattingString = $"+ {value1}; - {value1}; 0";
```

Your snippet should instead look like this:

```
double value1 = 29.1221321;
string formattingString = $"+ #.############; - #.############; 0";
Console.WriteLine(value1.ToString(formattingString));
```

With the added understanding that you do **not** want to use the hard coded number of decimal places (which is understandable given the precision available with `double`), I'm not aware of a way using interpolation. I'd recommend a simple extension method for it:

```
public static string ToSignedString(this double value) {
    if (value < 0)
        return $"-{value}";
    else if (value > 0)
        return $"+{value}";
    
    return "0";
}
```

I don't typically recommend extension methods, but I believe your reasoning for not wanting hard coded decimal places is perhaps the need for the code to be concise due to heavy use.

```
double value = 29.1221321;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToSignedString());
```

Not the most graceful solution, but it would work.

Comment: Hi i have mentioned i do not want to use second solution given with hardcoded "#" after decimal places

Comment: @eulercode Depending on what are you intending to calculate the required number of `#`?

Answer (score -1):

You try to reformat Value1 another time in the Console.WriteLine
Change it to :

> Console.WriteLine(formattingString);